# Tensor product of $\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am now studying about tensor product of vector spaces and modules. (I just saw a part of wiki) I'm considering about $\mathbb Z_3 \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z $ as an example. If I denote the basis element $(r,n) \in F (\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z) $ by $e_{rn} $, then by the relation used in definition of tensor product, $e_{rn}=(r+3k)ne_{11} $, so if we take $n=1$, we have that $(r+3k)e_{11} $ are all same in $\mathbb Z_3 \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z$. So it seems like just same to $\mathbb Z_3$.

1. Am I right? Or there are other structures? Or totally wrong?
2. If right, how show this?

   - Here $F (S) $ means the free object of $S $.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your notation but indeed, in general $M\otimes_RR\cong M$.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you are right, and this is a general property: for a commutative ring $R$ and an $R$-module $M$ the following isomorphism holds:

$$M \cong M \otimes_R R$$

via a pair of mutually inverse maps

$$
\begin{align}
m & \mapsto m \otimes 1_R \\
r\cdot m  & \leftarrow\!\shortmid m \otimes r
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. Now it's obvious.

Comment: Also, at least in the case of vector spaces, $\mathbb K \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbb K \simeq \mathbb K \simeq \mathbb K^*$, so "adjoining" any number of copies of $\mathbb K$ or $\mathbb K^*$ via tensor product to $V$ always leads to a space that is isomorphic to $V$ itself. Thus only the spaces $\mathbb K$, $V$, $V^*$ and all the tensor products of $V$ with $V^*$ (in whichever order and number) may be significantly different.